# Spring Rest with Angular 2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post, angular2-services, spring-hateoas

I am having problems with inserting new rows into database with my Angular 2 application.

The problem occures when i try to insert a new entry in database that has a foreign key to another table in the database. My two models defined in Spring are:

```
@Entity
public class A{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "A")
    private List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class B{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="aId")
    private A a;
    ...
}
```

Those two models in backend have their counterparts in the frontend. I added the _links part because Spring Rest api gives links instead of foreign keys:

```
export class A{
  id: number;

  b: B[];

  _links:{...}
  ...
}

export class B{
  id: number;

  a: A;

  _links:{...}
  ...
}
```

I created these models based on what information i get from api. For example, a get request on localhost:8080/api/b/1 gives:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/b/1"
    },
    "b" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/b/1"
    },
    "a" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/b/1/a"
    }
  }
}
```

I can easily insert new rows into table A (since it doesn't contain foreign keys) with my angular 2 service method shown bellow:

```
  createA(a: A): Observable<A[]>{
    return this.http.post(this.AUrl, a)
                    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
  }
```

Similarly, service method for creating a new model B looks like:

```
  createB(b: B): Observable<B[]>{
    return this.http.post(this.BUrl, b)
                    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
  }
```

My repositories in Spring are defined as:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="a", path="a", itemResourceRel="a")
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Integer>{
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="b", path="b", itemResourceRel="b"))
public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, Long>{
}
```

My repository configuration in Spring is:

```
  @Configuration
public class MyRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration{

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config){
        config.setBasePath("/api");
        config.exposeIdsFor(A.class);
        config.exposeIdsFor(B.class);
    }
}
```

When i try to insert a new row into the table B i get the following error in spring:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [......model.B] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=a, rootBeanClass=class ........model.B, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
```

I would like to know what exactly is the request payload for http post request supposed to look like, in order for the application to insert a new row of B into the database. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I have made a spring rest controler with this mapping:

```
@PostMapping("/api/b")
@ResponseBody
public String createServis(@RequestBody B b){

}
```

If I make a http post request with this payload (using curl or by some other means, but thats not the point):

```
{
    id:1,
    aId:1
}
```

or this one:

```
{
    id:1,
    a:{id:1}
}
```

or even this one:

```
{
    id:1,
    aId:1,
    a:{id:1}
}
```

The property a of the object b remains null / is not properly initialized.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about the 'AId' part. Is that mirrored in your angular implementation? Also, could you add the rest of the stacktrace, please? Maybe add the complete model of class B?

Comment: It is actualy 'aId'. It basicaly tells that the join should happen on table a, column id. In the database table B would have a new column called a_id and there it will put the foreign key in. as for the rest of the stacktrace i pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/raw/6KyM63Ux

Comment: I am aware of that. But to me it looks like this exact behavior is not mirrored in your angular implementation and hence your aId property of the B object is null. Can you show the code, where your a is connected to b on client side?

Comment: Other than having a property b: B[]; in model A and property a: A; in model B on client side there is no other connection. 

Before i call the createB method of the service i make sure that the parameter b has property a set to an instance of A. I get that instance from http.get()

Comment: I edited my post to clarify why i created the models in angular 2 like that. Should i create them differently?

Comment: This: http://localhost:4200/api/b/1/a seems wrong. There is no id given for an object of A. No wonder, it can't be inserted. Can you test an insert call with the appended ID of class A? You say it's the response of your get call on b/1? I will have a look into that tomorrow, on mobile right now.

Comment: localhost:4200/api/b/1/a is fine. I get that link from a http get. If I make a http get request to localhost:4200/api/b/1/a it will return the instance of A that is in the object B that has id 1. I inserted some rows into both tables via the database and all of the http gets work fine.

Comment: Another straw: since neither collectionResourceRel nor itemResourceRel aren't needed in your case, could you remove them for another test?

Comment: Removed them and still the same problem. Property a in object B is still null in the controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, running out of ideas. I guess you'll have to debug the shit out of your spring application too see, when your b.a becomes null..

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer here [Spring Rest: Cannot insert rows that have @ManyToOne column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929828/spring-rest-cannot-insert-rows-that-have-manytoone-column)

Basicaly you need to post:

```
{
    id: 1
    a: "http://localhost:4200/api/a/1"
}
```

to url localhost:4200/api/b