# Spring Rest: Cannot insert rows that have @ManyToOne column

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-post, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am following a spring getting started tutorial in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

I added another entity books that has @ManyToOne relation to Person entity.
Person entity has a new property called bikes and has a @OneToMany relation with Bike entity. Only thing that is different from the getting started project is the new attribute with its getter and setter:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Bike> bikes;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<Bike> getBikes() {
        return bikes;
    }

    public void setBikes(List<Bike> bikes) {
        this.bikes = bikes;
    }
}
```

Entity Bike is described bellow:

```
package hello;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Bike {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Person person;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

PersonRepository.java did not change from the tutorial:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

BikeRepository.java is the new repository i created that handles Bike requests:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "bikes", path = "bikes")
public interface BikeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Bike, Long> {
    List<Bike> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Looks pretty simple, right? I am supposed to be able to create a new Person using curl (just like in the tutorial):

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"firstName\" : \"Frodo\",  \"lastName\" : \"Baggins\" }" http://localhost:8080/people
```

And it works:

[image: Post on localhost:8080/person that creates a new Person object]

However, when i try to add a new Bike with the curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"name\" : \"Frodos Bike\",  \"person\" : {  \"firstName\" : \"Frodo\",  \"lastName\" : \"Baggins\" } }" http://localhost:8080/bikes
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I get the same error even when providing a "person_id" propertly like so:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"name\" : \"Frodos Bike\",  \"person_id\" : \"1\" }" http://localhost:8080/bikes
```

My question is: how can I add a new Bike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for your BikeRepository to know which `row` is represented by `Person : { firstName : "Frodo", lastName : "Baggins" }`. You have to tell your BikeRepository how to or where to query for that.

Try

`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"name\" : \Frodos Bike\",  \"person\" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1" }" http://localhost:8080/bikes`

That like will query `http://localhost:8080/people/1` for the `Person Entity`.

It will also work with parameters based query, just replace the `{id}` query with `http://localhost:8080/people?name='Frodo'`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try with `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"name\" : \"Frodos Bike\",  \"person\" : \"/people/1\" }" http://localhost:8080/bikes`

Comment: Thank you :D. I don't know how this combination didnt get to me in all this time...

Comment: How would you update the bike field on column person_id. I tried

`curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"name\" : \"Frodos Bike\",  \"person\" : \"http://localhost:8080/people/2\" }" http://localhost:8080/bikes/1`

but it doesnt work. PS there is a person with ID 2.

Comment: Why `PUT` doesn't work I don't know and I haven't find an answer yet. But if you would use `PATCH` it would work. This would also be the better choice to update objects since you only transfer these parts you want to update. `PUT` alway wants the whole object. ...(by the way `http://localhost:8080` is not needed)

Comment: `PUT` would work with `curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"_links": {"person": {"href" : "/people/2"}}} http://localhost:8080/bikes/1/person`