# Updating foreign keys in spring jpa hateoas

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, http-put

I am using the same code that is described on my other question: [Accessing data jpa with rest getting started + entity bike that has foreign key on person entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929828/spring-rest-cannot-insert-rows-that-have-manytoone-column)

The problem is that i cannot update the value person_id in the bike entity. I tried using this command:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"name\" : \"Frodos Bike name is changed\", \"person\" : \"http://localhost:8080/people/2\" }" http://localhost:8080/bikes/1
```

But it doesn't work. The name value changes, but the person_id stays the same.

Keep in mind that i do have a person which has ID = 2, and it is accesible at the url: http://localhost:8080/people/2

What is the correct way of updating this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PUT` would work with `curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"_links": {"person": {"href" : "/people/2"}}} http://localhost:8080/bikes/1/person`

or also with `PATCH` with `curl -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"name\" : \"Frodos Bike name is changed\", \"person\" : \"/people/2\" }" http://localhost:8080/bikes/1`